# When I input a number in char type, why i can't get a whole number?

Tags: c++, char, cin, cout

I input a number in char type variable. like 12 or 22. but, console show me a 1 or 2.
How i get a whole number 12 ,22 in console?

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    char a = 0;
    cin >> a;
    cout << a << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Here is console result.

```
12
1

C:\Users\kdwyh\source\repos\MyFirstProject\Debug\MyFirstProject.exe(프로세스 18464개)이(가) 종료되었습니다(코드: 0개).
이 창을 닫으려면 아무 키나 누르세요...
```

The reason I don't use int, string and something is because I want to get both number and Character in one variable.
So I want to see the results of combined numbers and character at the same time.
in that process i can't get a whole number.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int index = 0;
constexpr int pagenum = 10;

void chapterlist(void);

void nextlist(void);

void beforelist(void);

void movechapter(char a);


int main(void)
{   
    char userin = 0;
    bool toggle = 0;
    
    cout << "결과를 볼 챕터를 고르시오." << endl;
    
    chapterlist();

    cout << "다음 페이지로 이동: n" << endl;
    
    cin >> userin;

    if (userin == 'n')
    {
    backflash:

        while(toggle == 0)
        {
            nextlist();
            cin >> userin;

            if (userin == 'b')
            {
                toggle = 1;
                goto backflash;
            }
            else if (userin == 'n')
                continue;
            else
            {
                system("cls");
                movechapter(userin);
                break;
            }
        }

        while(toggle == 1)
        {
            beforelist();
            cin >> userin;

            if (userin == 'n')
            {
                toggle = 0;
                goto backflash;
            }
            else if (userin == 'b')
                continue;
            else
            {
                system("cls");
                movechapter(userin);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        system("cls");
        movechapter(userin);
    }
    
    return 0;
}

void chapterlist(void)
{
    int x = 0;

    for (x = index + 1; x <= index + 10; x++)
        cout << "Chapter." << x << endl;
}

void nextlist(void)
{
    system("cls");

    cout << "결과를 볼 챕터를 고르시오." << endl;

    index = index + pagenum;
    chapterlist();

    cout << "다음 페이지로 이동: n" << endl;
    cout << "이전 페이지로 이동: b" << endl;
}

void beforelist(void)
{
    system("cls");

    cout << "결과를 볼 챕터를 고르시오." << endl;

    index = index - pagenum;
    chapterlist();

    cout << "다음 페이지로 이동: n" << endl;
    cout << "이전 페이지로 이동: b" << endl;
}

void movechapter(char a)
{
    cout << "선택한 Chapter." << a << "의 결과입니다." << endl;
}
```

In movechapter(), console show me a is 1 or 2, not 12, 22.

Comment: Because `'1'` is a character and so is `'2'` in the string `"12"`. You read 'characters', any conversion (e.g. to `int`) happens after the characters are read.

Comment: umm i have to make decision what i want to ask. so complicated even i see.

Comment: It gets worse. [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) was the basic character set, but very limited. So then UTF-8, unicode and UTF-16 came along. (multi-byte characters). Both C and C++ provide basic input routines that allow reading the various character and numeric types that handle the conversion from char to numeric type for you. The wide-character types require special handling on input (though UTF-8 is generally automatically handled with basic output routines)

Comment: It would be great if you comment on what those korean letter means, so we can have a better understanding of your code

Comment: Not sure if I'm understanding your code correctly, you want the user to input `n` or `b` to go to next or previous page, and input a number to go to the corresponding chapter number?

Comment: I understand David. i must find another way to input.

Comment: You are exactly right. Ranoiaetep. and  cout << "선택한 Chapter." << a << "의 결과입니다." << endl; means "This is the result of the chapter.'a' you selected."

Comment: Actually i must add more code to make program i want. but, on the way, i find a error.

Answer (score 3):

First, you have to understand what a`char` type is.

> Character types: They can represent a single character, such as 'A' or '$'. The most basic type is `char`, which is a one-byte character. Other types are also provided for wider characters.

To simplify that, `char` can only hold one character.

Where as with your code, "12" is actually 2 separate characters, '1' and '2', and that's the reason it would not work.

Instead of declaring `a` as a `char` type, you could declare it as an `int` type, which is a type designed to hold numbers. So you would have:

```
int a = 0;
```

However, do note that `int` often has a maximum value of 2^31.

Or you could use `std::string` to store character strings. However, do note that if you wish to do any calculations to your `string` type, you would need to convert them to a number type first:

```
int myInt = std::stoi(myString);
```

---

### Edit:

So I have re-checked your code after your update, there is nothing wrong with using `std::string` in your case. You can still check if user have input `n` or `b` by:

```
if (userin == "n")
```

Note that you would use double quotation mark, or `"letter"`, around the content that you want to check.

On the other hand, you could use:

```
if(std::all_of(userin .begin(), userin.end(), ::isdigit))
```

To check if user have input a number.

Comment: So if i want to get '12', do i have to use char array?

Comment: Yes, you may use a character array.  That's what "strings" are in C: a null-terminated array of characters.  But if you're using C++, a better choice would be to use [std::string](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string).  If you'd prefer to have a value you can do arithmetic with, then you might instead use an [integer type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types), like "int".

Comment: @유장현 depends on your goal for the code. If you know that the user would only input a number, you would use a number type, like `int` or `long`

Comment: @Ranoiaetep Ok i try to use std::string. Thanks to answer my question!

Answer (score 0):

Although `char` is just a number, it's presumed to mean "single character" here for input. Fix this by asking for something else:

```
int a = 0;
```

You can always cast that to `char` as necessary, testing, of course, for overflow.

Comment: The reason why i use char is that i want to get two type of input. like 12 and 'R'. so i want to get them in same time in console.

Comment: You can have two different types of variable, like `int x` and `char y` then `std::cin >> x >> y` which will handle each type individually.

Comment: Thanks to your comment! Well, thay way seems good to make program easier. i will try then!

Answer (score 0):

You should be reading characters into a string, and then converting that string into an int. It would also probably make more sense to use something like `getline()` to read input, rather than `cin >> a`.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    std::string input_string;
    /* note that there is no function that will convert an int string
       to a char, only to an int. You can cast this to a char if needed,
       or bounds check like I do */
    int value;

    while(1) {
        getline(std::cin, input_string);
        /* std::stoi throws std::invalid_argument when given a string
           that doesn't start with a number */
        try {
            value = std::stoi(input_string);
        } catch (std::invalid_argument) {
            printf("Invalid number!\n");
            continue;
        }
        /* You wanted a char, the max value of a `char` is 255. If 
           you are happy for any value, this check can be removed */
        if (value > 255) {
            printf("Too big, input a number between 0-255\n");
            continue;
        }
        break;
    }
    printf("Number is %hhu\n", value);
}
```

Comment: Someting difficult to me...but i understand what you want to say to me. thanks!

Comment: You wouldn't have required to write the type specifiers, rather use `std::cout` to print instead (the code is of C++).